# tableview not reloading data after data update

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

having this view controller with two childs, the same type with two instances. the child has a tableview and a button to indicate that is Favorite or not, when button is clicked the button change is tincolor as expected but the second child does not reload is data as should do.

```
protocol favoritesUpdate{
 func uppdateFavorites()
}

class chatListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var type: Bool?
var data:[message]?
var filter: [Chat] = []//[NSManagedObject] = [] 
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let chatsRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "chats")
var chats: [Chat] = []
//let appDelegate =
var isfilter = false
var controllername: String?
var delegate: favoritesUpdate?
let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
lazy private var backgroundViewWhenDataIsEmpty: UIView = { return UINib(nibName: "nochat", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("type is \(type) in \(controllername)")
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fondo chat"))
    tableView.backgroundView?.alpha = 0.49
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("ya aparecio")
    self.readUserFromCD({ [weak self] _ in
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
        if type!{
            print("observing chats")
            observeChat()
        }
    })
}


 func readUserFromCD(_ completion:(_ data: Bool)->Void){        
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Chat>(entityName: "Chat")
            do {
                if type == false{
                    let temp =  try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    self.chats = temp.filter({
                        //$0.value(forKey: "favorite") as! Bool == true
                        if let value = $0.value(forKeyPath: "favorite"){
                            if value as! Bool == true {
                                return true
                            }
                        }
                        return false//if  != nil &&
                    })
                    //self.tableView.reloadData()
                }else{
                    self.chats = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    print(self.chats.count)
                }
                print("mostrando los valores de user \(chats)")
                completion(true)
            } catch {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            }
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("isFilter \(isfilter)")
        if !isfilter && chats.count > 0{
            tableView.backgroundView?.removeFromSuperview()
            tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fondo chat"))
            tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return chats.count
        }else if isfilter && filter.count > 0{
            tableView.backgroundView?.removeFromSuperview()
            tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fondo chat"))
            tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return filter.count
        }else{
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            showBackgroundIfEmpty()
        }
        return 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! chatsTableViewCell
        var user: NSManagedObject!
        if !isfilter{
            user = chats[indexPath.row]
        }else{
            user = filter[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.imagen.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
        cell.imagen.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.imagen.layer.borderColor = lightBlue.cgColor
        cell.imagen.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imagen.frame.width / 2
        cell.imagen.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.imagen.contentMode = .center
        if let url = user.value(forKey: "url") as? String{
            print("there is a image")
            //cell.imagen.sd_setHighlightedImage(with: URL(string: url), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.imagen.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ico_perfil"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.imagen.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        }else{
            print("there is not image")
            cell.imagen.contentMode = .center
        }
        if let  name = user.value(forKey: "name") as? String{
            cell.name.text = name
        }
        if let message = user.value(forKey: "message") as? String{
            cell.conversation.text = message
        }
        if let favorite = user.value(forKey: "favorite") as? Bool{
            if favorite{
                cell.favorites.tintColor = lightBlue
            }
        }
        cell.favorites.tag = indexPath.row
        //chats[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "favorite") as? Bool == true ? (cell.favorites.tintColor = lightBlue) : (cell.favorites.tintColor = grey)
        cell.favorites.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
        cell.favorites.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.setFavorite(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
func observeChat(){
    var key: String?
    Constants.refs.databaseChats.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
        print("the key \(snapshot.key) y \(snapshot.key.contains(String(requestManager.instance.user.id!)))")
        if snapshot.key.contains(String(requestManager.instance.user.id!)){
            key = snapshot.key
            if let snap = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                if let last = snap.last{
                    if let dat = last.value as? [String: Any]{
                        //let id = dat["id"] as! String
                        var message = dat["body"] as? String
                        let senderId = dat["senderId"] as! String
                        let recipientId = dat["recipientId"] as! String
                        var userid = ""
                        var name: String?
                        var preurl: String?
                        let id = snapshot.key
                        if recipientId != requestManager.instance.user.id!.description && senderId == requestManager.instance.user.id!.description{
                            userid = recipientId
                            if dat["attachmentType"] as? Int == 2 {
                                message = "le envio una imagen"
                            }
                        }else if recipientId == requestManager.instance.user.id!.description && senderId != requestManager.instance.user.id!.description {
                            userid = senderId
                            if dat["attachmentType"] as? Int == 2 {
                                message = "envió una imagen"
                            }
                        }
                        Constants.refs.databaseUser.child(userid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snap in
                            print(snap.value as Any)
                                let da = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                            name = da["name"] as? String
                            preurl = da["image"] as? String
                            self?.setChats(id: id, name: name!, message: message!, preurl: preurl!, key: id)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
    func setChats(id: String, name: String, message: String, preurl: String, key: String){
    print("values recibed \(name), \(message),\(preurl),\(key),\(id)")
    print("type is \(type) in \(controllername)")
    if type!{
        print("aqui llego")
        var miChat: Chat?
        //let managedContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Chat> = Chat.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", id)//NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Chat.id), self.id!)
        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if results.count > 0 {
                print("chat Found")
                miChat = results.first
                miChat?.message = message
                print("mi chat is \(miChat)")
                try managedContext.save()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("the values in \(self.chats.count)")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

//                  self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    // Fido not found, create Fido
                    print("not found \(id)")
                    miChat = Chat(context: managedContext)
                    miChat?.id = id
                    miChat?.name = name
                    miChat?.message = message
                    miChat?.url = preurl
                    miChat?.key = key
                    print(miChat)
                    try managedContext.save()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("the values in \(self.chats.count)")
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
//                  self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }else{
            print("no type")
        }       
    }
@objc func setFavorite(_ sender: UIButton){
    let value  = self.chats[sender.tag].value(forKey: "favorite") as? Bool
    value == true ? (sender.tintColor = lightBlue) : (sender.tintColor = grey)
    self.chats[sender.tag].setValue(!value!, forKey: "favorite")
    //let managedContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do{
        try managedContext.save()
        self.delegate?.uppdateFavorites()
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

now in the parent view controller the protocol function implementation

```
func uppdateFavorites() {
    self.favoritosVC.readUserFromCD({_ in
        self.favoritosVC.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

but the update is not happenig. what is the best way to achive this.
Edit: the problem thisn to be the delegate that is nil

Comment: Why is tableView "weak"? Either tableView has been deallocated or data is asynchronously updated and your calling reloadData to soon.

Comment: tableview is outlet created by xcode, so i make all outlet weak. after changin the the values in managed conted is the updateFavorites delegate is called